# firebase crashlytics not starting, shows loading icon

Tags: firebase, crashlytics-android

I just started using firebase crashlytics for my android project. Went through all the steps and it detected that application connection is ok. But when I press Crashlytics menu its showing that loading icon and I cant get any further? Its been like that for few hours now. Is this normal? Or does it mean there is an issue?
Screenshot of console added.

[image]

Comment: did you fix this issue?, I have the same issue..

Comment: One thing that I did which was not done - integrate Play Store account and Firebase. But it still did not work after that. I contacted google support and after half a day it started working.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I spent some hours doing and re-doing the steps with one project, then with another test project but always failed.

Comment: Do I have to ask support or just wait half of day?

Comment: I would suggest contacting support and then wait.

Comment: Have you fix this one now? Are you able to access Firebase Crashlytics?

Comment: while setting up firebase crashlytics, first time you have to forcefully crash you app, like throw IOException, you app will send event to crashlytics and it will get processed.
official docs ; https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android

Comment: @MarisMols how you connected with the support team? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: you have to mimic crash Aka make any runtime error to make your app send crash event to your Crashlytics console and refresh your Crashlytics it will be connected successfully

Comment: Still facing the same issue after forcefully crash into the app. Please help